# Iterate over array if the prop is there without getting 'cant iterate over undefined' error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have something like

```
if (this.props.fk_data) {
    if (this.props.fk_data.length > 0) {
       for (let fk_dataset of this.props.fk_data) {

       }
    }
}
```

I'd like to simplify the mess. I can put the `this.props.fk_data` into state in the constructor but I remember reading it's bad in React even though I can't remember why. The constructor looks like:

```
constructor(props) {
    let custom_methods = [
        'initializeOrClearState',
        'generateFKButtons',
        ...
    ];
    super(props, custom_methods);
    this.state = this.initializeOrClearState();
}
```

What is the best React way to simplify these if blocks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could write it like this:

```
for (let fk_dataset of (this.props.fk_data || [])) {
    // ...
}
```

Note that you don't need to handle the empty array case specially.

Although usually you will eventually want to display a placeholder or message if there are no items, in which case this is fine in my opinion:

```
if (this.props.fk_data && this.props.fk_data.length > 0) {
    for (let fk_dataset of this.props.fk_data) {
        // ...
    }
} else {
    // Show placeholder.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is less verbose (but also less readable, so you'll have to decide for yourself if it's worth it)

```
for (let fk_dataset of ( this.props.fk_data || [] ) ) {
    [...]
}
```

if `props` doesn't have an fk_data property, you'll iterate over an empty array (i.e. 0 times).

Comment: thanks boris, but I believe supr beat you by 15 seconds :)